# Check/ Decode auth0 Access Token

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, jwt, auth0

I need to know the time remaining in the Access Token and not the ID token or the token for browser flows. Checking the expiry of the token on http://www.jwt.io always returns 24 hours. However, the Access Token for the API should be longer than that. How can I check the expiring date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the authorization server provides an endpoint to get information about the token (the ideal would be to have [an Introspection endpoint as per the RFC7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2)), then it is easy to have this information.

Otherwise, if no endpoint is available, you have to keep in you memory the value in the `expires_in` parameter of your access token response (see [RFC6749 section 4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4)) and add the current timestamp to this value to get the exiration timestamp.

Please note that the access tokens you receive may be revoked by the authorization server thus the token will be invalid before that expiration time.

Another possibility if the access token is a signed Json Web Token (JWS - see [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515)), you could parse the token and check the `exp` claim (optional, but usually present in such context).